# Saving a HTML template clone reference in Javascript before adding it to the DOM

Tags: javascript

I would like to save a reference of a document fragment to have later access to it. Same access as with document.getElementbyId().

```
var test;

let template= = document.getElementById("templateId");
let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);

test=clone;
document.getElementById(destinationId).appendChild(clone);
```

If I debug test has all references and informations as the clone variable. But after I append the clone much information is lost.

The test variable should have the **reference** to the same document fragment (that stays in clone) which will be in the document.
I do not want to make a copy of the element, because I want to access it later by the variable test to modify for example the value of a label.

Comment: change your fourth line to `template.cloneNode(true);` this should solve it.

Comment: If i change the code to your suggestion I get a reference to the template object in the DOM. But i want a reference to the document fragment, which will be appended to the DOM as a copy of the template

Answer (score 0):

Use This Example

```
$("header.site-header").before($("header.site-header").clone();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First you missed a collumn at the end.I do not quite understand your answer. Which part do you mean witth with "header.site-header" ?

Comment: "header.site-header" means as you clone any Part. Add Class OR Id replace with "header.site-header" which you wish Clone.

Comment: First "header.site-header" Copy of header and Second "header.site-header"  is Location(Where You Put clone Part) Define.

Comment: I tried it with following code: 
var a= $("#templateId").before($("#destinationId").clone());
it stores the <template> element, but not the cloned element

Comment: Why are store in variable ?

Comment: You can Refer This link to get more Idea in this. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp

Comment: I want to access the node i insert in my HTML via this variable. Similiar to getElementbyId, but without using an Id.

Comment: Different Syntax in Jquery.